# Which DOF Adapter works with APS-C lenses?

Tags: lens-adapter, adapter, mobile

Which DOF Adapter works with APS-C lenses? I know about Beastgrip MK.2 and Ulanzi DOF Adapter but they need full frame lenses

Comment: This is ultimately just a variation of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: What device are you photographing on?  What APS-C lenses do you intend to use?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I don't see any if I quickly Google that. If you really want to use it with APS-C lenses **you have some options**:

1. Get the Sony E mount version (Ulanzi) and mount Sony E-mount APS-C lenses on it. They fit like that so it will work. For some lenses you might notice vignetting because of the limited coverage. Not sure if that can be done with Canon EF mount also.
2. Get either of the adapters and then buy a separate adapter from that mount to the APS-C mount you have lenses for.

**Some thoughts**

What a stupid name for an adapter type. I had to Google what it was. It should explain linking lenses to smartphones. I bet mounting a 16mm f4 lens won't give you that limited DOF anyway.

Why do you need it to accept APS-C lenses? If for pricing going for the Sony mount won't help much. Canon EF mount accepts very affordable second hand manual lenses. It will be a manual affair anyway.

Not sure if using 35mm film format lenses will result in vignetting. Not all APS-C lenses have limited field of view causing this effect. Some just work as well on full frame. Plus who knows how close these adapters match that field of view anyway. Maybe their coverage isn't full frame.

Comment: "What a stupid name for an adapter type.  I had to Google what it was." – That's just indicative of your personal ignorance, not any problem with generally accepted terminology.  What would you call it?

Comment: "It should explain linking lenses to smartphones." – DOF adapters did not originate with, and are not limited to, smartphones.

Comment: @xiota I see, similar to how your comment tells more about you than it does about me? I would think "lens adapter" makes more sense as a name.

Comment: DOF adapters have a particular construction that "lens adapter" does not convey.  I can think of at least five different types of adapters that could be referred to as "lens adapters".